# 1,414 lines of syslog has been written when computer starting up - is it normal?

Tags: release-loki, system, startup

My Elementary OS on `4.4.0-53-generic` kernel.

It writes about 1,414 lines `syslog` at every startup.

Actually *my computer starts a few seconds late today as never before*.

(Last night I run the command of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base linux-image-'uname -r' libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-tools` to fix the sound problem and I updated system via AppCenter)

Then I check the `syslog`. I realized that 1414 lines have been added when the computer starting up.

Then I thought that the logging may be relevant with late startup issue.

So adding 1,414 lines of syslog when computer starting up is normal?

Comment: My syslog is full of:

Dec  8 11:03:04 dago ureadahead[318]: ureadahead:33/stat: Ignored relative path
Dec  8 11:03:04 dago ureadahead[318]: ureadahead:33/cmdline: Ignored relative path

What about yours?

Comment: I've throw my all startup syslog onto pastebin -> http://pastebin.com/Y2jtkyTG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with 1,5k lines in the syslog at startup, it can be absolutely normal.

However, there might be some errors that cause slow startup indeed, for finding them you should look more for the time stamps and the log contents (than to the amount of information logged).

Looking at your log, it might be the wireless connection or the mount of a remote network drive that takes some more time than usual.

Comment: Thanks! Startup takes 20 seconds. The first 10 seconds of this for loading UEFI and loading Elementary OS takes the remaining time. However I'm sure about that 4-5 days ago, it takes only 3-4 seconds.